# Making the hamburger menu static is a good practice?

Tags: usability, ios, ipad, hamburger

I'm working on an app that should be feasible with every version of iPad. Currently I have designed the screens for the iPhone. 
This app is for a reputed bank and this app will be used by their customers for every need. This is more than a normal banking app.

**I just want to know is, is it suitable to make the hamburger menu static through out the app.**

What I have seen is, when clicking on the hamburger menu it appeared, when you don't want it you can hide the hamburger menu.

So making the hamburger menu static is a good UX practice for iPad?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by static? To me, static means that the hamburger menu cannot be interacted with. Do you mean persistent?

Comment: If by static, you mean "always showing", then I say yes. Especially on a mobile platform. Menus should always be easily accessible to the user even when not in use.

Comment: @dan1111 static means it can not hide, always open

Comment: @AaronJames static means it can not hide, always open

Comment: If the hamburger menu is always open is it not just a regular menu? The whole point of a hamburger menu is that is saves room by collapsing.

Comment: To create something feasible with every version of iPad is... challenging to say the least, only because you never know what Apple is going to change next without letting you know :D

Comment: @DasBeasto It does the same functions as usual hamburger menus. The only difference from other hamburger menus is, it always showing.

Comment: @LalindaSampath, but hiding is the crucial functionality that makes something a hamburger menu. No hiding, no hamburger.

Comment: @dan1111 yes, I accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, the answer is that **it depends on the content you're trying to display**.

What it sounds like you're describing is a [split view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ContentViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1). [[image: iOS split view from Human Interface guidelines]

This is a standard iPad pattern and it works well if you have many menu items AND don't need all of the screen real estate for your content. I would guess this isn't a good pattern for you as you're displaying financial data (tables and charts) that need as much screen as possible to be useful.

**Other Options**

Since split view doesn't work well for what you're talking about we can move to other options.

I would caution against the use of the hamburger menu (showing/hiding the sidebar) on iOS because it's not a standard pattern. If you have a lot of menu items it's a potential solution, but you'll notice that many apps have moved away from the hamburger. If you choose to use the hamburger you should test it.

What they've often switched to is the tab bar (Facebook & Spotify come to mind).[image: iOS tab bar]

I would look there first.